# How do I ignore all spelling errors in a Word 2013 document?

Tags: spell-check, microsoft-word-2013

In previous versions, the right-click pop-up on a misspelled word would allow me to ignore **all spelling** in that particular document. But it's not there anymore and I can find no reference to being able to do it, neither in the app nor online. Help?

Answer (score 11):

For Word 2013, if you want to ignore spelling errors for a particular document while still check spelling errors for other documents, you can go to the `Exceptions for:` section at the end of the `File -> Options -> Proofing` section.

Your current document should be selected in the drop-down as default. Check the `Hide spelling errors in this document only`.

Answer (score 9):

File >> Options >> Proofing

Should be an option to turn off grammar/spell-checking for your document.

[Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/check-spelling-and-grammar-HA102809598.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

File >> Options >> Proofing.
Uncheck "Check spelling as you type" and "Mark grammar errors as you type".

Here is a view of the [settings windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YhNs.png) (with relevant options highlighted).

For more information, see [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/937422).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the File >> Options >> Proofing setting is global.

An alternative is to use a different style for the affected areas, then select:

1. Modify style
2. Format
3. Language
4. Tick "Do not check spelling or grammar"

Answer (score 0):

file-> Options-> Proofing-> Exceptions for: -->  **check**[ Hide spelling errors in this document only] (& if you want to ignore grammar errors also then) **check**[ Hide grammar errors in this document only]